# Extension of Isovist concept for a point - to Isovist for a polygon

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

Math/Algorithm question, also posted in [math stachexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391120/extension-of-isovist-concept-for-a-point-to-isovist-for-a-polygon):

There is the concept of [Isovist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isovist)/[Visibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon) polygon. They both talking about volume of space **visible from a given point in space**.

My question: What is the algorithamic solution of this problem for a polygon - volume of space **visible from a given polygon in space**?

I started to thinking:

1. Reduce polygon to line, and then reduce line to point.
2. So there is the solution for a point, then the solution for line is the union of visibility region's (Isovist's) of it's (line) edges.
3. Then the solution for polygon is the union of all visibility region's of it's (polygon) edges.

Is that make sense?

Comment: There's a problem with your 2nd claim. It may happen that the visibility "from line" is more then the union of visibility regions from both line ends.